# Where should I put C# dll in Metro Style Appc#

Tags: microsoft-metro, dllimport

I am trying to import dll from Metro Style App.
But I don't know where should I put dll. Please reply to me.

Comment: What do you mean, by "Where should I put [it]"? Do you mean when adding references, or something else?

Comment: yeap like that. I try to use gsdll32.dll from Metro Style App like that "[DllImport(GhostScriptDLLName, EntryPoint = "gsapi_new_instance")]
 private static extern int gsapi_new_instance (out IntPtr pinstance, IntPtr caller_handle);" but I don't know that where should I reference dll.

Comment: In another way that I want to know that it is possible to reference and use c library dll from Metro style app.

Comment: You can't use Ghostscript in a Store app, it won't get past the validator.

Comment: Hello Hans Passant, I am trying to view PDF in metro style app without lauching reader(default pdf reader). So I am trying to convert pdf to image by using free converter library. Is there any other good ideas? If you have, Pls tell me. It will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can only reference DLLs built against WinRT. Typically these can be added via nuget, or alternatively added as a project, and using a project reference. Using other approaches is likely to fail certification, and not allow you to distribute your app to the general public.

Comment: You will certainly also be able to create own class library assemblies build against the .NET API for Windows Store apps or portable libraries and reference them in their compiled form. That should not fail the certification.

Comment: @JürgenBayer those would be compiled against WinRT, and would typically be a project reference...

Comment: Do you meant that I have to built that dll with WinRT? But I couldn't created it. I downloaded it. Actually, that dll is Win32 library. Is it possible to load? if possible, how can I reference?

Comment: @YuLi Win32 DLLs are not suitable for use in Windows Store (metro) applications

Comment: @Rowland Shaw,Thanks a lot. I clear it. It is very helpful to me.